# joomla custom forms log user out

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have a php script embeded into a Joomla! article via sorcerer plugin.

The embedded php script contains/renders a simple html form. The submit action submits to the same script with an added parameter (?action='submit').

Script checks whether this parameter is set thusly:

```
if(isset($_GET['action')){
// do the sql insert 
}else
{
//render the form
}
```

The submit action :

```
<input type='submit' value='Sumbit' action='http://wwww.mydomain.org.uk/page?     
action=submit'>
```

Now, the issue is that each and every time the submit button is pressed, the logged in user is logged out from Joomla!, and the database session expires.

This started to happen after the host upgraded my Joomla! to be on a different server. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing the code in the script…

Comment: <?php
 if (isset($_GET['action'])){
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$insert_sql= "INSERT INTO KOSRequest (user_id,created,IGN,LKL,KOS,Status) VALUES (".$user_id.",".$date.",'".$_POST['IGN']."',". $_POST['LKL'].",'".$_POST['KOS']."'";  
$db->setQuery($insert_sql);    
$db->execute();  
} else {

Comment: echo"
<form name='kos_entry' action='http://www.ospalliance.org.uk/JOOM/2-uncategorised/51-kill-on-sight-form?action=submit' method='POST'>
Player IGN <input type='text' name='IGN' required /><br />
Player Location :<input type='number' name='LKL' required /><br />
Reason: <textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='KOS'></textarea><br />
<input type='submit' value='Sumbit'>";
}
?>

Comment: Sorry that the code is split into 2 sections - it's too long to fit as comment otherwise

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, edit your question and add it there

Comment: I've asked my question again on a different post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930619/joomla-custom-form-logs-the-user-out-on-submission

Answer (score 0):

It seems a sort of conflict issue with some native joomla parameters our code execution about the session handling.

If you need joomla customization, consultancy or expertise team visits our site http://storejoomla.org

Comment: I found the issue - the form tag was not closed, as the html was encapsulated in echo, I guess it give no chance to show any error.